# Refresh a page with a time period

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some jQuery code to insert record in database. I need to reload the page within a time period. That means, when I click submit button, success message or error message will show first, and then the page will be reloaded after 5seconds.

My code:

```
(function($){        
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").click(function(){
            //alert("testing2.....")
            var num = /^[0-9]/;
            var date=$("#date").val();//alert(date);
            var sMan=$("#sMan").val();//alert(pType);
            var cName=$("#cName").val();
            var input_type=$("#input_type").val();
            var tamt=$("#tamt").val();
            var tpaid=$("#tpaid").val();

            //use the $.post() method to call insert.php file.. this is the ajax request
            $.post('action/b_payment.php', {
                date: date,
                sMan: sMan,
                cName: cName,
                input_type: input_type,
                tamt: tamt,
                tpaid :tpaid
            },
            function(data){
                $("#message").html(data);
                $("#submit").attr('disabled','disabled');
                $("#message").hide();
                $("#message").fadeIn(1500); //Fade in the data given by the insert.php file
                $( '#formId' ).each(function(){ //This code is for reload the page
                    window.location.reload(true);
                });
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
})(jQuery);
```

How can I display the message after a time period 5 seconds?

Comment: use setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 5000);

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using JavaScript timer

```
setInterval(function(){ //display message
},3000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
setTimeout(function() { window.location.reload(true); }, 5000);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to delay javascript code execution, you can use the setTimeout function.

```
// This code will execute after 5 seconds
setTimeout(function() {
    alert('Hello world');
}, 5000);
```

Answer (score -1):

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.location.reload(true); 
}, 5000);
```